# PySide Password Field not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside

I am new to PySide/PyQt, I am creating a dialogue box which accepts username and password. I am facing the error with password text-field.

As per documentation of PySide to create a password text field I am using

```
self.password_text = QtGui.QLineEdit.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)
```

but when I run the application, get the following error.

```
   self.password_text =QtGui.QLineEdit.echoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password) 
   TypeError: descriptor 'echoMode' requires a 'PySide.QtGui.QLineEdit' object but received a 'PySide.QtGui.QLineEdit.EchoMode
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're code is not creating a `QLineEdit`. You should do:

```
self.password_text=QtGui.QLineEdit()
self.password_text.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)
```

A bit more on your errors:

- `QtGui.QLineEdit.setEchoMode` is not a valid call. `setEchoMode` is a method of the class `QLineEdit`, so you need an instance of the class to call it (that's what the error message means). A valid call would be `QtGui.QLineEdit().setEchoMode`.
- If you look at the doc, you'll see that `setEchoMode` returns `void` (so in Python, nothing). So without the previous error, `self.password_text` would have been `None`.
  Usually in QT, you have to create the widget and then set it's property.

Comment: Year 2k19: QLineEdit now is under QtWidgets. So `QtWidgets.QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password` should be used.